# Where can I find the log of bluetooth enable and disable

Tags: bluetooth, logging

**Problem**

I have Samsung Note 20 and a Samsung Watch.  The watch wakes me up every morning between 4:42 and 4:43 am. This is independent of the time zone. It happens in NZ and Malaysia.  It happens even though I have "Do Not Disturb" on a time schedule.

I notice that the phone even disconnects from the car, while I am still sitting in the car (with it on).  It also disconnects from the car and watch when the phone is showing on an advert on an app. This happens often, maybe it's related to the ad that's being played.

**Information**

The notification is `Phone disconnected`. I have this notification on, to remind me if I  forget my phone.

**Assumption**

I  assume that bluetooth has been turned off or disabled.

**Question**

Where can I find the logs on bluetooth enable and disable, so that I can discover what process is responsible?

Comment: Run `adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager` command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on the "Enable Bluetooth HCI Snoop Log" option in the "Developer Settings" of your device.

The log Bluetooth log file is usually stored here:
/sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log
or here:
/data/misc/bluetooth/logs/btsnoop_hci.log

Comment: Hi. I don't have this option in my Android 10 device. Could you mention the device name and the Android version on which you tried this answer?

Comment: On Pixel 3a (Android 9). You can go to System > Advanced > "Developer options" > "Enable Bluetooth HCI Snoop Log". After enabling the setting, logs are stored here /data/misc/bluetooth/logs.

If you cannot find "Developer options", you need to enable them. You can enable them by tapping "Build number" in settings multiple times (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options).

Comment: I removed the tick because the file is no longer accessible directly.  I am still trying methods to access it.

Comment: My device was rooted so thats why I am able to access the files. You try these commands to get the logs:
1. `adb bugreport report`.
2. `unzip report.zip`.
After extracting the report.zip, the bluetooth logs can be found in `FS/data/misc/bluetooth/logs` folder. You can open the log file using a tool like WireShark.

Comment: I am confused, is this command on windows running adb ?  And I have plus-oned your reply as it does have merit.

Comment: [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) is a tool to communicate between a PC and an Android device. You are right, you need to run adb from a PC running windows(or other supported OS like Linux) while your mobile device is connected to the PC via USB cable.

Comment: Alternative is to generate bugreport directly from the phone. To genreate bugreport from the phone, you can go to "Developer options" (assuming you enabled them by following by comment above) and select "Take bug report". You will see the progress in the notification and when its finsihed you can tap the notification to upload the bugreport to a drive or email so you can access it.